# Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on string when building a PHP filtering system

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've recently built in a filtering system to filter mysql results in my application.

My current code is :

**PHP**

```
$type = $this->input->post("type");
  $name = $this->input->post("name");


  $brunches = "SELECT b.*, host FROM brunches b
  LEFT JOIN hosts ON hosts.id = b.hostid";
   $conditions = array();



   if(! empty($type)) {
     $conditions[] = "type='$type'";
   }
   if(! empty($name)) {
     $conditions[] = "name='$name'";
   }

   $sql = $brunches;
   if (count($conditions) > 0) {
     $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
   }

  $data['brunches'] = $sql->result();  //line 155

  $this->load->view('brunches-grid-view',$data);
}
```

for some reason I'm constantly getting the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on line 155` (added comment to line 155)

Comment: `$sql` is a string and doesn't have a method called `result()`.  Where you expecting it to execute the SQL for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to generate a query result

```
$sql= $this->db->query($sql);
$data['brunches'] = $sql->result();
```

more info on [how to generate query results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#generating-query-results)

Comment: This is so obvious as well. This was bad on my part. I guess i can only blame the lack of no sleep and being awake for 24 hours. How embarrassing! Thank you @vickel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your table stricture but I think there are few things missing. Just check this and compare your code with the tables.

1. $brunches sql string.
2. $conditions[] array key string
3. line 155

   $type   = $this->input->post("type");
   $name   = $this->input->post("name");

   $brunches = "SELECT b.*, h.host FROM brunches b LEFT JOIN hosts h ON h.id = b.hostid";

   $conditions = array();

   if(! empty($type))
   {
       $conditions[] = "type='".$type."'";
   }

   if(! empty($name))
   {
       $conditions[] = "name='".$name."'";
   }

   $sql = $brunches;

   if (count($conditions) > 0)
   {
       $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
   }

   $data['brunches'] = $this->db->query($sql)->result();  //line 155

   $this->load->view('brunches-grid-view', $data);